# Javascript validation and loops

Tags: javascript, html, loops, validation, checkbox

I'm learning basic web development and I'm VERY, VERY stuck on JavaScript form validation and loops. I need to validate **radio buttons**, **drop down selection**, **checkboxes**, **number selector**, and a box to **type in your name**. I think I'm on the right track for some of it but I could be completely wrong. I have 0 idea how to do a number selector (pin number between 1000-9999). The loop needs to read all the form fields and display their value in the console when submit button is pressed and validation passes. I've tried finding this stuff everywhere and have struggled a lot. I'll leave the code for each below, This is also my first post on here so if you need more info to help me please just let me know!

**For the enter your name box**

```
function validateForm() {
      let x = document.forms["whatisyourname"]["name"].value;
      if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**Radio button**

```
function validateForm() { 
var radios = document.getElementsByName("hair_color");
var formValid = false;
var i = 1;
while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;
}
if (!formValid) alert("Please select a hair option");
return formValid;
}
```

**Drop Down**

```
    function validate() {
 var ddl = document.getElementById("food");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "")
   {
    alert("Please select a food");
   }
}
```

**Check Boxes**

```
function valthisform() {
var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("hobby");
var okay=false;
for(var i=1,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
{
    if(checkboxs[i].checked)
    {
        okay=true;
        break;
    }
}
else alert("Please check 2 checkboxes");
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="whatisyourname" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <label class="wiyn" for="name">What is Your Name?</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="whatisyourname" name="name" minlength="5"><br>
        <br>
  
<label class="wiyff" for="foods">What is your favorite food?</label><br>
        <select name="foods" id="food">
          <option value=""selected disabled hidden>---Select---</option>
          <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
          <option value="macandcheese">Mac and Cheese</option>
          <option value="pancakes">Pancakes</option>
          <option value="frenchtoast">French Toast</option>
        </select>
<br>

<p class="p1">What is your hair color?</p>
 <input type="radio" id="Blonde" name="hair_color" value="Blonde">
 <label id="blonde" for="blonde">Blonde</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="Brown" name="hair_color" value="Brown">
 <label id="brown" for="brown">Brown</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="black" name="hair_color" value="black">
 <label id="black" for="black">Black</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="grey" name="hair_color" value="grey">
 <label id="grey" for="grey">Grey</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="Bald" name="hair_color" value="bald">
 <label id="Bald" for="bald">Bald</label><br>
 <input type="radio" id="other" name="hair_color" value="other">
 <label id="other" for="other">Other</label><br>
<br>

<p class="p2">What hobbies do you like (choose at least 2)?</p>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hobby1" name="hobby1" value="Playing Hockey">
 <label class="hobby" for="hobby1"> Playing Hockey</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hobby2" name="hobby2" value="Watching baseball">
 <label class="hobby" for="hobby2"> Watching baseball</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hobby3" name="hobby3" value="Fishing">
 <label class="hobby" for="hobby3"> Fishing</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hobby4" name="hobby4" value="Skateboarding">
 <label class="hobby" for="hobby4"> Skateboarding</label><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="hobby5" name="hobby5" value="Exercising">
 <label class="hobby" for="hobby5"> Exercising</label><br>
      </br>

<label class="pin" for="pin">Pin number (between 1000 and 9999):</label> <br>
  <input type="number" id="pin" name="pin" min="1000" max="9999">
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: @TheKNVB just added it

Comment: You have added validation to the "pin" field(i.e. the last line of the HTML code). The browser will handle it for you. The HTML code does not have the closing tag of form.

Comment: @TheKNVB does the rest of the validation look good?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 we have several validation attributes that can be used, which simplify the validation work significantly.

You can refer to [this web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) for detail.

However, the following sample code shows you how the validation attributes work:

```js
function validateForm(theForm) {
  let minHobbyCount = 2,
    hobbyCount = 0;
  let isValidate = theForm.checkValidity();

  if (isValidate) {
    theForm.hobby.forEach(h => {
      if (h.checked) {
        hobbyCount++;
      }
    })
    if (hobbyCount < minHobbyCount) {
      alert("Please check 2 checkboxes");
      isValidate=false;
    }
  }
  return isValidate;
}
```

```html
<form name="whatisyourname" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post">
  <label class="wiyn" for="name">What is Your Name?</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="whatisyourname" name="name" minlength="5" required><br>
  <br>

  <label class="wiyff" for="foods">What is your favorite food?</label><br>
  <select name="foods" id="food" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>---Select---</option>
    <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
    <option value="macandcheese">Mac and Cheese</option>
    <option value="pancakes">Pancakes</option>
    <option value="frenchtoast">French Toast</option>
  </select>
  <br>

  <p class="p1">What is your hair color?</p>
  <input type="radio" id="Blonde" name="hair_color" value="Blonde" required>
  <label id="blonde" for="blonde">Blonde</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="Brown" name="hair_color" value="Brown">
  <label id="brown" for="brown">Brown</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="black" name="hair_color" value="black">
  <label id="black" for="black">Black</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="grey" name="hair_color" value="grey">
  <label id="grey" for="grey">Grey</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="Bald" name="hair_color" value="bald">
  <label id="Bald" for="bald">Bald</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="hair_color" value="other">
  <label id="other" for="other">Other</label><br>
  <br>

  <p class="p2">What hobbies do you like (choose at least 2)?</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hobby1" name="hobby" value="Playing Hockey">
  <label class="hobby" for="hobby1"> Playing Hockey</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hobby2" name="hobby" value="Watching baseball">
  <label class="hobby" for="hobby2"> Watching baseball</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hobby3" name="hobby" value="Fishing">
  <label class="hobby" for="hobby3"> Fishing</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hobby4" name="hobby" value="Skateboarding">
  <label class="hobby" for="hobby4"> Skateboarding</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hobby5" name="hobby" value="Exercising">
  <label class="hobby" for="hobby5"> Exercising</label><br>
  <br>

  <label class="pin" for="pin">Pin number (between 1000 and 9999):</label> <br>
  <input type="number" id="pin" name="pin" min="1000" max="9999" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```